# Upload files to server

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm making my first MVC Project for the school and ran into this problem:

I'm building an Classifieds web page where user can upload pictures of what they want to sale,
As far as i understand the best practice to to  this, is store the Image path into the Db table and the file goes into a file in the server. So with the path  i can retrieve that specific image in the web page.

The problem is that i'm  able to store the image only in my local computer not in the server where i've published the project.

How can i upload this file to a server instead of my local computer?

This is my controller:

```
public ActionResult CreateAnuncio( HttpPostedFileBase thePic)
{
    if (thePic != null && thePic.ContentLength > 0)
    {
        // string filePath = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("http://example.com/Sites/mvc/classifieds/Images/slider"), Path.GetFileName(Nuevo.id + thePic.FileName)); // Does not Work

        string filePath = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Images/slider/"), Path.GetFileName(thePic.FileName)); //Works only for local saving

        thePic.SaveAs(filePath);
    }
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

Basically the error I'm getting is:

> http://example.com/Sites/mvc/classifieds/Images/slider' is not a valid virtual path.

Here is the View:

```
<form id="contact_form" method="post" action="/classifieds/CreateAnuncio" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="thePic"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Send">
 </form>
```

Comment: Can we see the form that posts to this action?

Comment: I just posted the form...  I removed some other non-related content

Comment: The line that is commented "// string filePath " is where im putting the server path but is not working.

Comment: Consider if you can use DB - it is generally much easier to set reasonable permissions to read/write to DB than correctly setting up permissions and impersonation to allow writing to files on server (or even harder outside of server).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are running your code in the same server, you can use the relative path to that folder.

```
 var filePath = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/classifieds/Images/slider"),
                                      Path.GetFileName(Nuevo.id + thePic.FileName));
```

If it is a shared location in the network, but accessible from the server where you deployed your code, that should also work

```
var filePath = Path.Combine(\\myFileServerName\files\",
                                        Path.GetFileName(Nuevo.id + thePic.FileName));
```

**In both the cases, Make sure that the directory's permission is updated so that ASP.NET can write to that.**

Right click on the folder and go to ***properties->Security*** and update the permissions.

Comment: I haven't create any virtual directory in the IIS, so I guess this is where the error "is not a valid virtual path." is coming from

Comment: Your second suggestion (save to network share) is generally pain to implement as it requires giving everyone R/W access to the share OR complicated impersonation setup...