# Simple file upload returns NULL?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to do my first simple file upload in MVC 5. I'm following a bunch of examples I've found but for some reason in my "Create" ActionResult the uploadFile is always coming in as NULL so the upload code is never running. Anyone see what I might be doing wrong?

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}


<h2>Documents.</h2>
<h4>Upload a new document.</h4>

<div class="well">
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Documents", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    <h3>Select a file to upload. </h3>

    <input type="file" name="files" value="" multiple="multiple" />

    <input type="submit" value="Upload your file" title="Upload" />

    <div style="color:Red;font-size:14px">@ViewBag.Message</div>
}
</div>
```

Here is my controller:

```
// POST: Documents/Create
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Create(HttpPostedFileBase uploadFile)
        {
            try
            {
                if(uploadFile != null && uploadFile.ContentLength > 0)
                {

                    string filePath = Server.MapPath("../SiteDocuments" + uploadFile.FileName);

                    uploadFile.SaveAs(filePath);
                }

                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return View();
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your file input element's name should match to your action method parameter name.

So update your HTML markup to have the same `name` attribute value.

```
<input type="file" name="uploadFile" value="" multiple="multiple" />
```

and your action method will be

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(HttpPostedFileBase uploadFile)
{
  // do something
}
```

**Or** change your action method parameter name to match with your file input element name.

```
<input type="file" name="files" value="" multiple="multiple" />
```

and your action method will be

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(HttpPostedFileBase files)
{
    if(files!= null && files.ContentLength > 0)
    {
       // do something
    }
}
```

When you add `multiple="multiple"` attribute to the input element, the browser will allow the end user to select more than one file at a time. In that case If your action method parameter is a single instance of `HttpPostedFileBase` object, It will receive the first file from the selected `n` files. If you want all the files, You may change your parameter to a collection such as

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> files)
{
    if (files != null && files.Any())
    {
        foreach (var file in files)
        {
            if (file.ContentLength > 0)
            {
                //do something
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that was it. Once I got the element names matching and my missing slash in the .MapPath it worked.

Comment: @Caverman :You are welcome ! IMHO, Try to use `Path.Combine` instead of manually concatenating, as shown in this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26111460/40521)

Comment: I initially had that from an example I found but I went back to the simple Server.MapPath to see if that made any kind of difference, which of course it didn't. I'll go back tot he Path.Combine.